# References are positioned under the chapter/section number in HTML using tex4ht

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, html

I am converting documents to (X)HTML using `tex4ht`. The program works well, but the only thing that doesn't is the references.

I included a table of contents and made links using the `hyperref` package. However, when I use the links from the ToC or ref to labels (placed directly under the title), they come out wrong.

If I use the article `documentclass`, it doesn't show any section title at all, it just starts with the text. If I use the report `documentclass` it shows the title, but not: 'Chapter #'.

Minimal code is:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The first chapter}
\label{chap1}
Some text

\chapter{The second chapter}
Some text and \ref{chap1}.

\end{document}
```

I then used the `MiKTeX` version of `tex4ht`. However, I have tried on MacTeX and this gives the same result.

How can I show the full titles when using links?

Comment: after `htlatex filename` the result looks like this: http://pastehtml.com/view/c1ztxuj4g.html . does you have different result?

Comment: right, if you add a lot of text, say a few paragraphs from www.lipsum.com, you will see that when using the links, the part 'chapter 1' is not shown

Comment: I uploaded an example: http://pastehtml.com/view/c1zxy1q62.html

Comment: As things stand, I really don't see the issue here.